# Is there a problem in using System.Web in a desktop application

Tags: .net, asp.net

I just added System.Web reference to a dll assembly, the assembly is for windows applications and for web applications.

IF the assembly will be deployed on a server, System.Web will be shared using GAC, and there is no overhead.

But what about windows clients.  I am wondering if there are extra resources or any kind of problems when System.Web is loaded into memory?

Thanks

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: Why I should? What is difficult to understand?

Comment: the use of the word "devil" may be confusing to some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the client only has the [.Net Framework Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) installed. This could be a problem.

The Client Profile is the default installation on an end-user PC for .Net 4.

Normally Visual Studio is intelligent enough to warn you about this situation, but you need to set the "Target framework" to a "* Client profile" in the Properties of a project.

Comment: An important update is that "starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Client Profile has been discontinued and only the full redistributable package is available". Might be worth to edit the answer.